# Reading TXT files from AWS S3 from Rstudio via cloudyr/aws.s3 library ☁️

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rstudio

I'm trying to use `aws.s3` library to read from AWS S3 from my Rstudio session. I'm following [this instructions](http://datascience.ibm.com/blog/read-and-write-data-to-and-from-amazon-s3-buckets-in-rstudio/). The following lines

```
obj <-get_object("s3://my_bucket/myfile.csv")  
csvcharobj <- rawToChar(obj)  
con <- textConnection(csvcharobj)  
data <- read.csv(file = con)
```

works just fine for reading `csv` files. But the following alternative returns error for `txt` files.

```
obj <-get_object("s3://my_bucket/myfile.txt")  
csvcharobj <- rawToChar(obj)  
con <- textConnection(csvcharobj)  
data <- read.table(file = con)  
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
line 1 did not have 6 elements
```

Any suggested solution to this issue? Thank you.

Comment: is your text file tabular formatted, what i mean is that read.table need the data to be in tabular format like csv
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was an issue with my particular txt file or the particular s3 path. The above block works for another txt file.

I think the question answer might be still helpful to keep. But, I leave that to the moderators' decisions of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fill for empty elements.
read.table(file = con, fill = TRUE)